# Global variable oddities in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does IE nuke window.ABC variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606847/why-does-ie-nuke-window-abc-variables)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        if(typeof q === "undefined"){
            window.q = {test: "test"};
        }
        alert("1="+q) 
    </script>
    <script>
        alert("2="+q)
        if(typeof q === "undefined"){
            var q = {};
        }
        alert("3="+q.test)
    </script>
    <script>
        alert("4="+q.test)
    </script>
</body>
```

In IE8, the result is

```
1=[object Object]
2=undefined
3=undefined
4=undefined
```

The second `script` seems to  override the `q` of `window`.

If I change the code to `window.q = {test: "test"};` of the first `script` to `q={test:"test"}`, the result will be the same as other browsers.

Is this a bug in IE?

Comment: This seems to only happen in IE 8.  IE 9+ work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug to me. In IE 10, the above yields

```
1=[object Object]
2=[object Object]
3=test
4=test
```

This is the same behaviour as Firefox.

EDIT: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/2635726/1641070 and [Why does IE nuke window.ABC variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606847/why-does-ie-nuke-window-abc-variables)