# override variable in javascript function

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

Firstly I want to say that I was searching some information about scope variables in javascript (e.g [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)) and I was trying to understand why my code behaves like that but finally I really don't know. I can't override var a in my function in function, I can do this only using `a = 6;` without var. Why a is undefined before if statement and overriding this variable ? Why there is no result like this:

> 5
>
> equal 5
> equal 6

I have something like this instead:

> undefined
>
> not equal 5
> equal 6

Here's my code:

```
    var a = 5;

function something(){
    console.log(a);
    if(a == 5){
        console.log('equal 5')
    }
    else{
        console.log('not equal 5');
    }    
   var a = 6;
    
    function test(){
        if(a == 6){
        console.log('equal 6');
    }
    else{
        console.log('not equal 6')
    }
    }    
    test();    
}
something();
```

Answer (score 8):

This is because javascript variable hoisting.

Your code is equal to:

```
var a = 5;

function something(){
    var a;  // here
    console.log(a); // a is the local variable which is undefined
    if(a == 5){
        console.log('equal 5')
    }
    else{
        console.log('not equal 5'); // a is undefined so not equal 5
    }    

    a = 6; // a is assigned to 6

    function test(){
        if(a == 6){
            console.log('equal 6');  // a is 6 here
        }
        else{
            console.log('not equal 6')
        }
    }    
    test();    
}
something();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because when you declare `var a = 6` the second time you are overriding the first declaration of `a`, i.e. `var a = 5`. So when you define the function `something()`, `a` has not yet been defined, hence `console.log(a)` returns undefined.

However when you replace the second declaration of `a` with just `a = 6` the first declaration remains valid, you just change the value of `a` afterwards and so you get the expected result:

```
5 
equal 5
equal 6
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634410/javascript-redeclared-global-variable-overrides-old-value) for more discussion.